# How to connect a google sheet to the right project

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have a free gmail account. On google drive I have a google sheets where,using api, I check among rows through a unique key and if the row already exist I update data in that row. if not I create a new row.

well, sometimes I get this error: Google Sheets says "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:471794752687'."

But if I go on google cloud console to increase quota, I see all the log as 0 and the project number is different.

the owner/creator of the google sheet is the same account that I use to log in the google cloud console.

Please help me
thanks
Claudio